# Layout posicionado abaixo do header ao clicar em link

Tags: javascript, rolamento

alguém sabe como fazer com que, ao clicar em qualquer postagem no tumblr, tags e páginas, o layout pule o header e fique posicionado direto nas postagens?
Estou tentando algo como abaixo, porém não sei continuar, o site é esse: https://anotherplacemagazine.tumblr.com/:

```
$('.this-is-permalink').click(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
```

obrigado!